# Image capture does not show preview of camera and file becomes invalid

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera, save-image

I am trying to create an application that captures an image and stores it into my internal storage. When I change my codefrom File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); to  File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM); (due to absence of SD card on my phone), it does not open the camera and a file is stored in my DCIM folder. The file stored will be have an error "File format isn't supported or files are corrupted". If I use Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES instead it shows a preview of the camera and imageView but no files will be stored.

I am new and any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My code is as shown below

```
public static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE =1;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        File imgFile = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewID);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
    }

}



String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    //File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return  image;
}

static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: im sorry i dont understand what you mean. when I use File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);, I am able to open the camera with intent. but when I change it to File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);, I cannot view the camera. I do not understand why this is happening

Comment: `it does not open the camera and a file is stored in my DCIM folder.` I have no idea why the Camera app would not start. But besides of that, you are creating that file yourself. Dont do that. You only need a File instance.

Comment: thank you for your reply. could you give me an example of only giving a file instance? and do you have any idea why the file saved in my DCIM folder gives an error "File format isn't supported or files are corrupted"? i forgot to mention that in my original post and have edited it.

Comment: File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "picture.jpg"); And your file has 0 bytes file lenght. Apparently this is considered corrupted ;-).

Comment: Noted. how do i  add byte file length? Sorry i am really new at this and quite clueless

Comment: Well if you now would use only a File instance you would not have a file with 0 bytes lenght anymore. And if you could manage to let the Camera app take a picture the Camera app would create that file.

Comment: i have successfully completed the task. it was a problem with my file_path.xml all along. thank you so much blackapps for your help!! i would not have been able to complete this without your help :) :) really appreciate you spending your time helping me